# Attaching multiple azure subscriptions to a single subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Is is possible to attach multiple azure subscription to one master subscription so that we can access all the data from a single subscription instead of integrating with multiple subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single subscription, but you can use Azure Management groups https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview

> If your organization has many Azure subscriptions, you may need a way
> to efficiently manage access, policies, and compliance for those
> subscriptions. Management groups provide a governance scope above
> subscriptions. You organize subscriptions into management groups; the
> governance conditions you apply cascade by inheritance to all
> associated subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you for your response Shriraj. So does management group has its own subscription?
I need to integrate these details in our tool and the basic requirement for that is to add subscription details at our environment by creating subscription node.

Comment: No it does not have its own subscription